# Rails complex filter with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a project in which I have to show groups.

Following models are involved

**Group**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups

  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "creator_id"

  belongs_to :group_status

  has_many :matches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked, :through => :matches, :source => :macther

  has_many :inverse_matches , :class_name => "Match" , :foreign_key => "matcher_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_by, :through => :inverse_matches, :source => :group

  enum status: %w[active inactive]

  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  
  has_one :setting, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy #, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :invited, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend

  has_many :inverse_friendships , :class_name => "Friendship" , :foreign_key => "friend_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invited_by, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups

  has_many :group_creations, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => 'Group'
  has_many :group_statuses

  
  has_many :matches, dependent: :destroy
  
  enum gender: %w[male female other]
end
```

**UserGroup**

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group

    enum status: %w[pending joined reported]
    attr_accessor :invite_id
end
```

**Match**

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :matcher, :class_name => "Group"

  belongs_to :user
  enum status: %w[like match unlike block blocked report reported]
end
```

First show groups according to user's preference like age, gender and group member's count and than show rest of users.

What I am doing is first exclude all groups which don't meet user preference  and show remaining ones, than show those which don't meet user's preferance.

This is how algo looks like

1- find groups which don't match group member's count

```
group_member_count_check = Group.joins(:users).joined_group.group('groups.id')
                                        .having("count(groups.id) != #{setting.group_member_count}").pluck(:id)
```

2- find groups which don't meet gender preference

```
if setting.male_only
  gender_check = Group.joins(:users).joined_group.where('users.gender !=?', 0).pluck(:id)
elsif setting.female_only
  gender_check = Group.joins(:users).joined_group.where('users.gender !=?', 1).pluck(:id)
end
```

3- than remove groups which contain blocked user's by current user

```
blocked_users = current_user.friendships.where(friendships: {status: 2}).pluck(:friend_id) + 
                current_user.inverse_friendships.where(friendships: {status: 2}).pluck(:user_id)
blocked_group_ids = Group.joins(:users).joined_group.where(users: {id: blocked_users}).pluck(:id)
```

4- remove already liked/disliked groups

```
already_liked_or_matched_id = (group.matches.where(status: [0,1,3,4,5,6]).pluck(:matcher_id)  
      + current_user.matches.where(status: [2]).pluck(:matcher_id)).uniq
```

**Now first return groups excluding above extracted groups**

```
groups = Group.includes(:group_status, :users)
                      .where(status: 'active', spot_light_enabled: false)
                      .where.not(id: group_member_count_check +  gender_check +blocked_group_ids + already_liked_or_matched_id  )
                      .near([latitude, longitude], setting.max_distace, order: 'random()').page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
```

**If no preferred group remaining than show other groups**

```
if groups.length.zero?
          groups = Group.includes(:group_status, :users).where(status: 'active')
                              .where(id: gender_check + group_member_count_check)
                              .where.not(id: blocked_group_ids + already_liked_or_matched_id )
                              .near([latitude, longitude], 10000, order: 'random()').page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
        end
```

Than response is like this

```
{ 
   groups: groups, 
   pagination: pagination_dict(Group.where.not(id: blocked_group_ids ).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page]))
}
```

**SCHEMAS**

```
  create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "user_name"
    t.string "authentication_token"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.text "bio"
    t.date "dob"
    t.integer "age"
    t.integer "gender"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.decimal "latitude", precision: 15, scale: 6
    t.decimal "longitude", precision: 15, scale: 6
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.boolean "creator", default: false
    t.boolean "is_premium", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "instant_match_allow", default: 1
    t.integer "spot_light_allow", default: 1
    t.boolean "is_blocked", default: false
    t.boolean "is_new", default: true
    t.index ["authentication_token"], name: "index_users_on_authentication_token"
    t.index ["phone_number"], name: "index_users_on_phone_number", unique: true
    t.index ["user_name"], name: "index_users_on_user_name", unique: true
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "group_status_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.decimal "latitude", precision: 15, scale: 6
    t.decimal "longitude", precision: 15, scale: 6
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "creator_id"
    t.integer "instant_match_allow", default: 1
    t.integer "spot_light_allow", default: 1
    t.boolean "spot_light_enabled", default: false
    t.datetime "spot_light_time"
    t.integer "place_id"
    t.index ["group_status_id"], name: "index_groups_on_group_status_id"
  end

  create_table "user_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.boolean "creator", default: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "matcher_id"
    t.integer "status"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "chat_id"
  end
```

**NOW ISSUES**

1- Major one that there are too many queries (I have to place some more checks yet exclude already shown groups etc.)

2- pagination don't work according to expectation (skip some pages due switch from preferred to other groups)

what would be the preferred way to manage this?

Comment: Hey – is it possible to see the schema for `groups`, and `user_groups` as well as the `user_groups` model? I suspect that a lot of these joins are unnecessary but that's just speculation until I am in the full context of the architecture

Comment: @DamilareOlusakin Updated question with model relations & schemas

Answer (score 1):

For quick refactoring, let us consider named scopes and the following approach.

- First, Find groups by user preference
- Find other groups by excluding the preferred groups
- Concat the two groups and apply pagination

For example, Group class may have the following scopes.
Please note that I couldn't test it and you may still need to refactor to make it work.

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :setting, to: :user, prefix: true # for accessing setting with `user_setting` method

  scope :status_active, -> { where(status: 'active') }
  scope :spot_light_disalbed, -> { where(spot_light_enabled: false) }
  
  scope :filter_blocked_groups, ->(blocked_users_id) { where.not(users: { id: blocked_users_id }) }
  scope :filter_by_gender_setting, -> { where('users.gender == ?', user_setting.male_only ? 0 : 1) }
  scope :filter_by_group_member_count, -> { group('groups.id').having("count(groups.id) == #{user_setting.group_member_count}") }
  
  scope :paginate, ->(page, per_page) { page(page).per(per_page) }
  scope :near_groups, ->(distance) { near([latitude, longitude], distance, order: 'random()') }
end

# Find groups by user preference
preferred_groups = Group.includes(:group_status, :users).joins(:users).joined_group
         .status_active
         .spot_light_disalbed
         .filter_blocked_groups(blocked_users_id)
         .filter_by_gender_setting
         .filter_by_group_member_count
         .near_groups(setting.max_distace)

# Find other groups by excluding the preferred groups 
other_groups = Group.includes(:group_status, :users).joins(:users).joined_group
               .where.not(id: preferred_groups.ids)
               .near_groups(10_000)

# Concat the two groups and apply pagination
groups = (preferred_groups + other_groups).paginate(params[:page], params[:per_page])
```

I didn't include the `already_liked_or_matched_id` query as the query isn't clear to me. U can add it likewise. The benefits of the above approach are..

- We are making only two queries to `groups` table
- Readability

Hope this helps a little. I believe there are more scopes for optimizations though. You can also consider implementing [query pattern](https://github.com/Selleo/pattern#query) by moving all those queries to a separate class.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, scopes make it really readable. 
but according to my understanding it fails the purpose of pagination, like if there are 1000 records, it 'll always fetch 1000 record than apply pagination to get first 20 from that 1000, shouldn't it fetch only 20 records only?

Comment: I am not sure if pagination will improve performance here as we would have to do all the computation first. Rather calculating the result once and use of memorization seems a better idea to me. However can't we still do pagination on the separate results(preferred groups, other groups) by appending the paginate scope?The main point was to share that we can calculate the preferred groups first and exclude them later for fetching other groups using fewer database calls.

Comment: get your point, moreover this query don't work "where('users.gender == ?', user_setting.male_only ? 0 : 1)", like if there are 4 members in a group and only one with gender male and rest are females, it 'll still consider it as male group.

Comment: @Muhammad Faisal Iqbal will this `where.not('users.gender != ?', user_setting.male_only ? 0 : 1)` work?

Comment: no, seems have to use subquery to manage this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462398/rails-all-users-in-a-group-with-gender-male