# Rails all users in a group with gender male

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have following models

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end
```

**Group**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end
```

**UserGroup**

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
end
```

I want all the groups which have only male members using

```
Group.joins(:users).where(users: {gender: 'male'}).distinct
```

but it does is, even if there is just one user is male and rest are females, it still return that group.
what I want is to return group only if all users are males.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get all those group ids from the user groups where the user gender is `female` and use them with a `NOT IN` clause, to filter out all those groups matching those ids:

```
with users(id, gender) as (values (1, 'male'), (2, 'female')),
     groups(id, name) as (values (1, '1st'), (2, '2nd')),
     user_groups(id, user_id, group_id) as (values (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1))
select *
from groups g
where g.id not in (
    select ug.group_id
    from user_groups ug
    inner join users u on u.id = ug.user_id
    where u.gender = 'female'
)
```

The ActiveRecord version might look like this:

```
Group.where.not(
  id: UserGroup.joins(:user)
               .where(users: { gender: 'female' })
               .select(:group_id)
)
```